# Looping within a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, iteration

can regex able to find a patter to this?

> {{foo.bar1.bar2.bar3}}

where in the groups would be

> $1 = foo $2 = bar1 $3 = bar2 $4 = bar3 and so on..

it would be like re-doing the expression over and over again until it fails to get a match.

the current expression i am working on is

```
(?:\{{2})([\w]+).([\w]+)(?:\}{2})
```

Here's a link from regexr.

> http://regexr.com?3203h

--

ok I guess i didn't explain well what I'm trying to achieve here.

let's say I am trying to replace all

**.barX** inside a **{{foo . . . }}**

my expected results should be

```
$foo->bar1->bar2->bar3
```

Comment: Why don'y you just use `#(\w+)#` pattern to catch words with no `.` and `{}`?

Comment: Is regex really the best way to do this? Why don't you just strip off the braces on the ends and use `explode`?

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming no braces are allowed within the match:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%(?<=     # Assert that the previous character(s) are either
     \{\{      # {{
    |          # or
     \.        # .
    )          # End of lookbehind
    [^{}.]*    # Match any number of characters besides braces/dots.
    (?=        # Assert that the following regex can be matched here:
     (?:       # Try to match
      \.       #  a dot, followed by
      [^{}]*   #  any number of characters except braces
     )?        # optionally
     \}\}      # Match }}
    )          # End of lookahead%x', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: you sir, is a regex god LoL. though it didn't work using preg_replace. since what I wanted to replace are the '.barX' only. ill edit the question for more info.

Comment: @kapitanluffy: Not sure I understand. Your edit to the question suggests that you *don't* want to replace the texts, only the delimiters around them (changing `{{foo.bar1.bar2.bar3}}` into `$foo->bar1->bar2->bar3`). Is that correct? Because that's a completely different question.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. it could be something like this too $foo[bar1][bar2][bar3]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but it's relatively painless to just split the string on periods like so:

```
$str = "{{foo.bar1.bar2.bar3}}";
$str = str_replace(array("{","}"), "", $str);
$values = explode(".", $str);

print_r($values);  // Yields an array with values foo, bar1, bar2, and bar3
```

**EDIT:** In response to your question edit, you could replace all `barX` in a string by doing the following:

```
$str = "{{foo.bar1.bar2.bar3}}";
$newStr = preg_replace("#bar\d#, "hi", $str);

echo $newStr; // outputs "{{foo.hi.hi.hi}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP person, but I managed to construct this piece of code here:

```
preg_match_all("([a-z0-9]+)",
"{{foo.bar1.bar2.bar3}}",
$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach($out[0] as $val)
{
echo($val);
echo("<br>");
}
```

The code above prints the following:

```
foo 
bar1
bar2
bar3
```

It should allow you to exhaustively search a given string by using a simple regular expression. I think that you should also be able to get what you want by removing the braces and splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the correct syntax in PHP, for pulling out the results, but you could do:

```
\{{2}(\w+)(?:\.(\w+))*\}{2}
```

That would capture the first hit in the first capturing group and the rest in second capturing group. regexr.com is lacking the ability to show that as far as I can see though. Try out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No. It would capture the first hit in `$1` and the last one in `$2`. Everything in-between would be overwritten by the last repetition.

Comment: Edited my reply, you're correct, the variables $2 would be overwritten, but the result would still hold all matches. This is simple in .NET where you just ask the match object (_System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match_) like this: `for(int i=0;i<match.Groups[1].Captures.Count;i++) string capture = match.Groups[1].Captures[i].Value;`

Comment: @TimPietzcker (forgot to add reference to you in my previous comment)